# Cognos: Using rank() across multiple columns to order bar chart

Tags: cognos

I have some example data like this table:

[image: table]

where the left table is currently the data I have and I want to order by year, company, and product (based on total cost). Currently, the user chooses the year and company on the prompt screen and I am trying to obtain something like a top ten list per year per company based on the total cost per product. I would like my data to sort to the table on the right with keeping track of the billing code area, but not sorting by it. I have been able to write a SQL code that will sort it using a group by, but I cannot add the billing code area. I need the billing code area to display the information in a bar chart. 
I have tried using the rank function in Cognos, but I can only do it for one column. I have also tried concatenating the 3 columns together, but no luck with that either. Is there any way to use rank() for 3 columns?

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you have two different tasks:

1. Calculate top 5
   AFAIR you can use rank() like this:

   ```
   rank([total_cost] for [Country],[Year],[Product])
   ```
2. List all billing area codes. It's not so simple. There is no special function for it (shame on them). So you can write custom query for it using features of you DB or, better, fake concatenation with repeater object or crosstab with master-detail relationship inserted in Billing Area Code field.

Comment: Whenever I use rank([total_cost]) my report will run, but adding company, year, and product pulls up an error even though it says it's a valid report. For number 2, my issue is adding the billing area code to the series of the bar chart.